# Adding Hibernate to an Android Project (Mistaken usage of core class)

Tags: java, android, hibernate

Our primary focus is a java-based desktop application. The data for our application is stored in an H2 database using Hibernate. The H2 database runs in server mode so that other clients can connect to it.

Will a Android application be possible to build to view the data hosted on a server. When I include hibernate jar's in my android application libs folder I get the following errors.

```
   [dx] trouble processing "javax/transaction/Transaction.class":
   [dx] 
   [dx] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
   [dx] when not building a core library.
   [dx] 
   [dx] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
   [dx] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
   [dx] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
   [dx] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
   [dx] going on.
   [dx] 
   [dx] However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
   [dx] namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
   [dx] from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
   [dx] assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
   [dx] compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
   [dx] It is also often of questionable legality.
   [dx] 
   [dx] If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
   [dx] appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
   [dx] distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
   [dx] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
   [dx] 
   [dx] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
   [dx] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
   [dx] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
   [dx] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
   [dx] application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
   [dx] system. You will be to blame for this problem.
   [dx] 
   [dx] If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
   [dx] core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
   [dx] repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
   [dx] your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
   [dx] conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
   [dx] you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
   [dx] that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
   [dx] lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
   [dx] 
   [dx] 1 error; aborting
```

There are two required Hibernate libraries that use the javax namespace (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.1.0.1-Final.jar and jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar).

- It tries to combine all of the libraries together into the .apk and throws a exception because it finds a class using a reserved namespace.
- Classes could conflict with system (core) classes that are part of Android/Java.

I believe the last paragraph of this error/warning applies to what I am trying to do.

- Would using a tool like JarJar help?
- How does repackaging code work with licensing?
- Would it be difficult to repackage all of the code?
- Why would a 3rd party create a package in javax anyway?

Edit: I am using ant to compile the Android project via the auto-generated build file and the command "ant debug".

Comment: I wonder if you googled before SO. The first few results on "android hibernate" are obviously where your answer lies.

Comment: Of course I did. I posted here because they do not answer my question. Please try to keep your comments constructive. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have googled. The first 2 results gives you the answer to your question. And this is me being constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate libraries are for JDK applications on desktops and servers. They dont work with Android. SqlLite is one of the main reasons why Hibernate may never work for Android. Its so simple to use.

If you include it by force, you will get Dalvik errors. The same errors you get when you include 2 android.jar's, or rt.jar.

Comment: So you are saying that it is actually not possible at all? Do you have any kind of reference for that? It's the same as when I googled... people say it's overkill and not to use it... but that does not apply to my situation. I have encountered the errors you are talking about, and that is what this question is about. The fact is, I already have a persistence layer using Hibernate for the desktop application, and I need to be able to retrieve the data from the SQL server on Android, which is not hosted on the Android device, and hence, not SQLite. I am looking for potential solutions for this.

Comment: If your data is hosted on a server, not on a android device, why are you trying to install hibernate ? Do you believe hibernate to be a database client that will replicate your data magically to your android device so that you wont have to write some kind of socket stuff ? Your question and objective just changed. Frankly, I am confused on what you are trying to do. Change your question, and make it more relevant to what you are trying to do ?

Comment: They dont work with Android. Actually means "it is actually not possible at all".

Comment: I'm confused by your confusion. My objective is stated before the compile error and my questions are stated after. There is a SQL database that is using Hibernate to map objects to it. We then want to view the data on an Android device. Since the objects are saved via Hibernate (by the desktop application), it would make sense to load them via Hibernate (except for the errors that I now know Hibernate has with Android). If it is not possible, I will need to find another solution. This question is exploring one out of many potential solutions. Why would a tool like JarJar not work?

Comment: @shaddow, I am trying to be helpful here, but you seem to want to not leave your stand about compiling hibernate on android. Dude, study up hibernate. I think you will find it revealing that your fundamentals need to strengthened. What is "making sense" to you is technically completely screwed. Its like saying, why cant ios code compile on android, just because it works on ios that looks like my android phone. No more responses from me on this topic.